# How to write numbers in landscape and the full width

Tags: fontsize, landscape

I want to simply write the numbers 2 to 9 as large as possible, across the page, in landscape mode and centred vertically and horizontally. I would like the numbers to take the full width of the page.  Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{vplace}
\centering
{\fontsize{70}{84} \selectfont 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}
\end{vplace}
\end{document}
```

I don't like this solution at all however.  I am also not convinced it will actually print properly in landscape mode.  Do I instead need to write the numbers vertically (rotated 90 degrees) in portrait mode to get them to print properly?  The numbers also don't seem to be horizontally centred.

Some notes: I am only using memoir as it gives the vplace environment.  I manually selected the font so it would stretch and the font size so it would fit.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal here? You can print the entire document using the `standalone` class as well. This results in a cropped version of the content, which you can then "fit" to a page when printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `graphicx` package offers the `\resizebox` macro which can be used to scale your numbers to the whole available textwidth:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\fontsize{70}{84}\selectfont 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}%
\vfill\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the thin lines show the geometry of the page)

Comment: @book Welcome!... and a suggestion for simplifying: you don't really need `\fontsize{70}{84}\selectfont ` because `\resizebox` is going to do all the scaling regardless of the `\fontsize` that you specify. :)

Comment: @sgmoye Nooo, without it the normal font will just be scaled up. This font is meant to be displayed in normal size, not in such a big font. If one uses a fontsize which is nearly right, it will be much better to read.

Comment: @sgmoye Try `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\tiny text}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{text}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\Huge text}

\end{document}` and look at the different boldness of the letters

Comment: @book Quite right! Well spotted.

Comment: @sgmoye :) And thanks a lot for biding me welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Using `hfill` in between the numbers spaces them equally. Also `\vfill` takes care of the vertical centering. Is this what you were looking for?

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}\vfill
  {\centering\fontsize{70}{84}\selectfont%
    2 \hfill 3 \hfill 4 \hfill 5 \hfill 6 \hfill 7 \hfill 8 \hfill 9%
  }
\vfill\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could potentially enlarge the Numbers a bit more, if you'd shrink the documents side-borders and enlarging the font a bit.

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage[landscape, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}\vfill
  {\centering\fontsize{130}{84}\selectfont%
    2 \hfill 3 \hfill 4 \hfill 5 \hfill 6 \hfill 7 \hfill 8 \hfill 9%
  }\vfill\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This version doesn't fit all the numbers into one line for me. The 9 is lost.

Comment: Did you maybe misplace the `%` in the corresponding line?

Comment: This is what I am trying http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/I92aWHBm

Comment: Is there a warning in your .log-file or something? For me it works as expected when i copy your code. Note, that i use TeXLive and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I am just using pdflatex. There is "Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
"

Comment: Sorry, but i can't reproduce your error, even though i also tried using `pdflatex`. You could try pasting your code in an online compiler like http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/latex.php and download your file from there. Let's see, if that works for you!

Comment: Hmm.. That works perfectly. How odd!  I am using TeX Live 2015/Debian on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you give me some background about your setup (OS, Editor, LaTeX-Distribution)?

Comment: I am using TeX Live 2015/Debian on Ubuntu 16.04. The editor is emacs.

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

That part is almost the same of Tim Hilt, but with a bit simplified code. If figures are too big, you only have to change the `204` by any lower number. The figures will be vertically centered and filling all the page width in all cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\leavevmode\vfill
\fontsize{204}{0} \selectfont 2\hfill 3\hfill
4\hfill 5\hfill 6\hfill 7\hfill 8\hfill 9 
\vfill
\end{document}
```

If the figures are still small, use a number up to 313 but also add the option `a3paper` to geometry, or in case of do not have a A3 printer or you want a bigger banner:

[image: mwe2]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{poster}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{300}{0}\selectfont
\poster[vcenter=true,hcenter=true,
paperwidth=21cm,imagewidth=21cm,]
{23456789}
\end{document}
```

It could be in more than two pages, and or without overlap between pages, but it is no so easy guess the result.